# RSpec's stub_chain returns stub even when it does not include full chain of scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, named-scope, stub

I ran into an issue with my RSpec specifications and ActiveRecord scopes today.

I have a controller that executes code similar to this

```
@customers = Customer.active.with_counts.order('name asc')
```

‘active’ and ‘with_counts’ are scopes on the Customer model.

I used to have a specification that used stub_chain like this:

```
Customer.stub_chain(:with_counts, :order).with('name asc') { [mock_customer] }
```

I did not expect this to succeed since the controller included the ‘active’ scope but to my surprise it succeeded without any problems.

I guess that the ‘active’ scope is called on the real Customer class and returns something that the stub_chain sort of connects to and it therefore appears to work.

How can I write my specification to avoid this kind of issue when I chain ActiveRecord scopes?

Note that the actual call in the controller will not always used both scopes - it is dependent on filtering so just wrapping everything in a new method is not a way that I am keen to go.